# Bug using breqn and babel

Tags: luatex, breqn

I've hit a bug that I cannot fix (no warnings/errors in the logs).

Here is a mwe:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
  \[\{A, B, C\}\]

  \selectlanguage{french}
  \[\{A, B, C\}\]

  \selectlanguage{english}
  \[\{A, B, C\}\]
\end{document}
```

I use the following command to compile:

```
$ latexmk -lualatex bug.tex
```

The output is as follows, the commas are mapped to a `\Gamma` symbol !?

[image: Output]

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this ?

```
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)
$ latexmk --version
Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Jan. 2018. Version 4.55
```

Comment: `breqn` is a nice proof-of-concept, but it's incompatible with a wealth of packages.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483852/2388

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `babel-french` module does `\std@math@comma` upon entering and also exiting French language blocks.

This resets the mathcode for the comma to the standard, but `breqn` wants that the mathcode stays `"8000`.

Simply make `\std@math@comma` to do nothing.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{breqn}

\makeatletter
\let\std@math@comma\relax
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[\{A, B, C\}\]

\selectlanguage{french}
\[\{A, B, C\}\]

\selectlanguage{english}
\[\{A, B, C\}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You should be aware that `breqn` is not really compatible with several package and is better not used in serious typesetting tasks.

Comment: Great investigation egreg, many thanks for the detailed explanations !

Answer (score 5):

For `lualatex` use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for this particular mwe but throws tons of errors for my huge document. I also see that unicode-math is quite eqperimental ?

Comment: No, unicode-math is not experimental. Show your preamble!